# How to automate key press on Android emulator on mac with Robot?

Tags: java, android, macos, automation, appium

I am attempting to automate a few steps on an Android emulator using the espresso driver with appium.  There is a pop-up window that appears when trying to allow location permission that the Espresso driver can't see.  I'm currently attempting to force a couple enter clicks using the following code:

```
Robot robot;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But using this only gets me the following error:

```
java[61315:813119] pid(61315)/euid(765933194) is calling TIS/TSM in non-main thread environment, ERROR : This is NOT allowed. Please call TIS/TSM in main thread!!!
```

All of this is on a Macbook, and my test code is in IntelliJ with the emulator launched from Android Studio.  I have tried disabling the main thread scanner in xcode, but that doesn't seem to extend to IntelliJ or appium.  Is there a way for me to force apple to ignore this check or to force this block of code to the "main thread"?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is about how to get through the location permission dialog, you can use [GrantPermissionRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule) which allows you to grant permission in your tests.

```
@Rule public GrantPermissionRule permissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```